# Django inspectdb ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: django, oracle

Im trying to import existing oracle tables in django.
Installed cx_oracle and i did all the steps for django to communicate with my oracle db.

```
import cx_Oracle

con = cx_Oracle.connect("PYTHON","PYTHON", "METDBR")

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from ICUSTOMER")
res = cur.fetchall()
for row in res:
    print(row)
```

works fine....

when im trying to inspect the table with the command

```
python manage.py inspectdb icustomer
```

i get
Unable to inspect table 'icustomer'
The error was: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is about letter case.

By default, Oracle stores table names in UPPERCASE. If you (or whoever created the table) used mixed case and enclosed table name into double quotes, you have to reference the table exactly like that: using the same letter case (as created), enclosed into double quotes.

Therefore, check exact table name.

Comment: neither works ICUSTOMER and icustomer both returns same message...but thanks for the comment....my oracale DB table is ICUSTOMER

Comment: this is a long shot, but you could try and set the schema name before the table name. In that way, your script should now which table to query: 


python manage.py inspectdb schema_name.icustomer

Comment: @PaulC. tried it both in upper and lower case ,both schema and table no luck... thank u anyway

Answer (score 0):

Check the `USER` that is configured in your default `ENGINE`, this is very probably *not* the user `PYTHON`.

You must than *qualify* the inspected table as `PYTHON.ICUSTOMER`

**and** grant the access on it the the *engine user* (while connected as `PYTHON`)

```
GRANT SELECT on PYTHON.ICUSTOMER to <engine user>;
```

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':   'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME':     'METDBR',
        'USER':     'PYTHON',
        'PASSWORD': 'PYTHON',
       # 'HOST': 'GRATHMETDBR',
       # 'PORT': '1521',
    }
}

Comment: OK @IliasBardis , last guess;) Is the `ICUSTOMER` realy a table (and not a view, materialized view or something else?). Check with `select * from user_objects where object_name = 'ICUSTOMER'`